# React Hook SetState Causing Infinite Loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, infinite-loop, setstate

Below is my code, I am attempting to call setState inside of my logout button as this button only renders when Auth0 isLoggedIn is true.
This seems to be causing an infinite loop, my guess is because the Auth0 API is being called
every time. I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35lXWvCuM8o
The only difference is I am attempting to call setState without an onClick function,
can anyone please explain to me the issue and a fix, thank you in advance!

I understand I can use localStorage to maintain a users Logged in Session, but I am doing this purely to learn React Hooks,

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useCallback } from "react";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import { ValueContext } from "./ValueContext";

const LogoutButton = () => {
  const [login, setLogin] = useContext(ValueContext);

  const { logout, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
  const updateLogin = () => {
    setLogin({ loggedIn: "false" });
  };

  return (
    isAuthenticated && (
      <>
        <button onClick={() => logout()}>Log Out</button>
        <h1>{login.loggedIn}</h1>
        {updateLogin()}
      </>
    )
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `updateLogin()` inside of your render function, so you're setting `loggedIn: true` every render. Don't put functions or console logs directly inside of the return function, put them inside of the main `LogoutButton` function body if you must. But `updateLogin()` should only be called inside of some onPress.

Comment: I changed my button to this:  <button onClick={() => logout(), updateLogin()}>
        Log Out
      </button>

Comment: but now I am getting an infinite loop of re renders.

Comment: I'm confused at what you're trying to accomplish here. I don't know how Auth0 works, but I assume you don't want to call `logout` and `updateLogin` ( which just logs you in ) in the same button.

Comment: I am trying to call auth0's login function which authenticates the user through auth0. at the same time the user authenticates, I want to update a global variable 'loggedIn' through context so that I can serenader my other components to give the user to new access to certain things they couldn't access when not logged in, which is why I originally tried to invoke updateLogin() by itself without onClick

Comment: Then why are you calling Auth0's `logout` if you're trying to log the user into Auth0?

Comment: Please check the updated code, I am trying to log the user out with Auth0 logout, at the same time, update my global value loggedIn to equal 'false' so other components re render to give access to only what a user can access when they're logged out

Comment: You still have the `{updateLogin()}` inside of a render method. It's going to keep updating state, then triggering itself again on the next render. Put `logout()` inside of your `updateLogin` function body and call that inside of the button's onPress.

Comment: I did that, and I can see the global state updates, however it seems once the logout through auth0 occurs, the global state resets back to the pre-updated value, on the tutorial I followed, Dev ed talks about using prevState to update the global context, however he is updating an array, and I am updating a single string global value, are you aware of a way to update using prevState for a string?

Comment: I reposted the question with the code you suggested, but not sure how to stop the value from resetting back to false, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64627375/setstate-updates-but-does-not-save/64627894?noredirect=1#comment114276324_64627894

Comment: Determine where the value is being set to false. I think you are confusing yourself with different concepts here. You have access to the value of "prevState" within the current value of `login`.

Answer (score 0):

You call updateLogin() every time the component renders. This sets the state variabel loggedIn. This will cause the component to render again and the process keeps looping.

Answer (score 0):

> The only difference is I am attempting to call setState without an onClick function

This is a big difference! setState should not be called in render function's main body, or at least, call it conditionaly. Otherwise you will get setState -> render -> setState -> render ->... it's endless.

You can try this:

```
    let alreadySet = false;

    const LogoutButton = () => {
    const [login, setLogin] = useContext(ValueContext);
    const { logout, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
    const updateLogin = () => {
      setLogin({loggedIn:'false'});
    };

    if(!alreadySet){
      alreadySet = true;
      updateLogin()
    }

    return ( 
    isAuthenticated && (
      <>
      <button onClick={() => logout()}>
        Log Out
      </button>   
      <h1>{login.loggedIn}</h1>
      </>
    )
```

Notice this

```
    let alreadySet = false;
....
{
    if(!alreadySet){
      alreadySet = true;
      updateLogin()
    }
}
```

It means loggedIn will only be updated once. Is it what you want? If it's not. You can updated your question with more details :)

Comment: I added the snippet you're referring to and am now getting a Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. 
updateLogin
src/components/LogoutButton.js:14
  11 | const { logout, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
  12 | const updateLogin = () => {
  13 |  /*  logout(); */
> 14 |   setLogin({loggedIn:'false'});
     | ^ 
src/components/LogoutButton.js:22
  19 |    let alreadySet = false;
  20 |     if(!alreadySet){
  21 |       alreadySet = true;
 |       updateLogin()
   |     }

Comment: Okay I changed the snippet  tolet alreadySet = false;
    if(!alreadySet && isLoggedIn){
      alreadySet = true;
      updateLogin()
    }

Comment: Now the app works and correctly shows the login button, but once I click login, and the logout button is rendered, I get an infinite loop of the setLogin again, so I need to figure out how to prevent it from reupdating the alreadySet back to false, any ideas?

Comment: Hey Josh, sorry for late reply, we should move "let alreadySet = false;" outside of the  LogoutButton function

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use updateLogin when isAuthenticated is true, you can add useEffect hook.

like this

```js
useEffect(()=>{ if (isAuthenticated){
   setLogin({loggedIn:'false'});
}},[isAuthenticated, setLogin] );
```