# SetState Updates but does not save

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, infinite-loop, setstate

Below is my code, I am attempting to setState a string global context value,
the string exists by itself and is not apart of an array of variables,
When I click login, I can see the h1 containing the global value login.loggedin updating to true as requested, however when the login finishes and auth0 redirects back to the app, the value is no longer changed to login and goes back to false,
On the tutorial I followed, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35lXWvCuM8o
Dev ed talks about using prevState to make sure it  correctly assigns the value,
however I am unsure how to use prevState for a string instead of the array he uses in his example, can someone please explain to me how set state can be showing as working but not saving and a possible fix? I even placed the loginwithredirect after the set state but is it possible the loginwithredirect is happening before the state change can finish processing?

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
import { ValueContext } from './ValueContext'
const LoginButton = () => {
  const { loginWithRedirect, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();

  const [login, setLogin] = useContext(ValueContext); 

    const updateLogin = () => {
    
    setLogin({loggedIn:'true'});
    console.log(login.loggedIn + " = login.loggedinvalue after update")
    console.log('true log')
    loginWithRedirect()
  };  

  return (
    !isAuthenticated && (
      <>
      <button onClick={() => updateLogin() }>
        Log In
      </button>
      <h1>{login.loggedIn}</h1>
        </>
    )
  )
}

----------
```

is this happening because I am not submitting the page? It seems that would make hooks quite limiting if you need to submit, so I am guessing that's not it either

Answer (score 0):

I'm only guessing here.

I'm assuming that when you call `loginWithRedirect` the app navigates away from your app (to Auth0? site), then user authenticates, and then the browser redirects back to your app. If this happens, whatever you saved in your `ValueContext` context will be reset to its initial state. During the initialisation of the `ValueContext` you need to take into account current user authentication.

Also, it seems that `isAuthenticated` flag provided by `useAuth0` hook has pretty much the same meaning as your `ValueContext.login` flag. Do you actually need `login` flag? If you need it, you have to keep the value of `ValueContext.login` in sync with `isAuthenticated` at all time to avoid any odd behaviours.

Comment: Yes isAuthenticated already has the same meaning, I am doing this purely to learn more about how to use reactHooks, what do you mean by "During the initialisation of the ValueContext you need to take into account current user authentication."

Comment: I mean that when you initialise `ValueContext` you need to set the value of the `login` flag to a correct value. You need to check if user is already logged in or not. If you always set `login=false`, then after every page reload your flag will be reset to false.

Comment: Could you show me through a snippet exactly how that would be initialized? also im guessing the if statement would occur in updateLogin, could you please provide me snippets of how to accomplish this I am a bit confused